# "error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax" on MonoDevelop C#

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop, linux-mint

When I try to do a project i get:

```
Getting restore information for project /home/user/Projects/myApp/myApp/myApp.csproj
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.203/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(54,5) : error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')". Method '[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier' not found. The invocation of the static method must be in the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), for example, $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)). Check that all parameters are defined, of the correct type, and specified in the proper order.
Unable to create package spec for project. '/home/user/Projects/myApp/myApp/myApp.csproj'
```

And when I try to compile i get:

```
Error: NuGet packages need to be restored before compiling. The NuGet MSBuild targets, which are required for build, are missing. NuGet MSBuild targets are generated when restoring NuGet packages. (myApp)
```

How can I compile it? or what i need do for that this run?

Comment: https://github.com/dotdevelop/dotdevelop/issues/40 Impossible when you have .NET 5 SDK installed (`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.203/`). Switch to VSCode please.

Comment: Do you want to see a screenshot of VSCode or how?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp